# Find a expression using pgf $G_X$ for the probability that $X$ is divisible by 4.

Tags: probability, divisibility, generating-functions

A random variable $X$ has probability generating function $G_X$.

(a) Find a simple expression using $G_X$ for the probability that $X$ is even. *Hint: consider the value of $G_X(-1)$*.

(b) Suggest a similar expression for the probability that $X$ is divisible by 4 -- be creative about what values of the generating function you might evaluate!

I had no problem with solving a simpler question in part (a), but am really struggling with part (b).

Answer (score 0):

In part (a) you used two numbers such that both are square roots of 1. Can you extend this to something that involves 4? Hint: you need 4 numbers.

> Find a, b, c, d, such that $$aG(i)+bG(-1)+cG(-i)+dG(1) = \sum_{4|n} p(n). $$

Comment: @Naet Math: many thanks for your advice! Through using this approach, I get: $G_X(i) = P(X=0)+iP(X=1)-P(X=2)-iP(X=3)+P(X=4)+iP(X=5)+\ldots \\ 
 G_X(-i) = P(X=0)-iP(X=1)-P(X=2)+iP(X=3)+P(X=4)-iP(X=5)+\ldots  \\ 
 G_X(1) = P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+iP(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)+\ldots \\ 
 G_X(-1) = P(X=0)-P(X=1)+P(X=2)-P(X=3)+P(X=4)-P(X=5)+\ldots    \\$

Comment: By summing up these equations we get that $P(X\:is\:divisible\:by\:4) = \frac{G_X(i)+G_X(-i)+G_X(1)+G_X(-1)}{4}$. 

Is this the correct answer, or I've done something wrongly?

Comment: But that’s what I get by summing up the four expressions above: $4P(X=0)+4P(X=4)+4P(X=8)+\ldots$ Everything else seems to cancel out...

Comment: Right! Then you are done. Sorry I didn't read your last comment carefully.